# How to get data synchonously in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function

```
isDeploymentAdminAvailable(deployment){
  let customQuery = {
    equalTo: this.selectedDeploy.key
  }

  this.authService.fnGetDataUsingCustomQuery(FirebaseDb.firebasedeploymentAdminTable, customQuery).subscribe(
    (rec: any) => {
      rec.forEach((reccord: any) => {
        reccord.key = reccord.$key;
      });
      this.deployAdminData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rec));

    });

  if(this.deployAdminData!=null && Object.keys(this.deployAdminData).length>0){
    return true;

  }

  return false;

}
```

As this part is checked immediately after the **subscribe** method, all time it returns **false**.

```
if(this.deployAdminData!=null && Object.keys(this.deployAdminData).length>0){
    return true;
}
```

How can I call this method synchronously or handles the situation in which I can return the correct data?

Comment: You can't :) You have to do these checks inside the callback, use map instead of subscribe. And wherever you are returning this boolean, do the subscribe there.